# Ajax for loop with unique property

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having an issue with a for loop. I've gotten pretty far in my property path, but I've hit a snag with a unique property.

(data.response.result.PropertyUnits.PropertyUnit.UnitSpace)

The next level is a unique number (4456424, etc.). Is there a way to just target the next level so I can run this in my loop for each unit? This is where I need to get my data.

Thank you

Comment: Please update your question with some example code.

Comment: You mean something like `data.response.result.PropertyUnits.PropertyUnit.UnitSpace["4456424"]...`?

Comment: I am trying to target data.response.result.PropertyUnits.PropertyUnit.UnitSpace["4456424"]["@attributes"].Status, and then data.response.result.PropertyUnits.PropertyUnit.UnitSpace["416435"]["@attributes"].Status, etc. if that helps

Comment: `data.response.result.PropertyUnits.PropertyUnit.UnitSpace["416435"]["@attributes"].Status`